# How to insert images/flags on visualforce page to show the outcome of exceptions and invalid field values

Tags: visualforce, exception, images, queryexception

I have a requirement in which I have to show flags/images in VF page in case of any exceptions ... For Eg. If for a field say Receipt__c = true but if the attachments is not added by user for that record, an exception table with an "image" and message that "no image attached" should be displayed.
I saw examples with formula fields and corresponding images as a way but this is not certainly what the use case is...
Please suggest.

Comment: To those who voted to close the question, it is a very valid question about how to use Visualforce. Just because it doesn't include specific code doesn't mean that it is an invalid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Visualforce element `apex:pageMessage` and do a rerender of that tag on the page. It takes a `severity` attribute that will show you various strengths.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm

Comment: hie David... actually I want to display images ( warning sign , stop sign, a flag etc ) for invalid user inputs..  IS there any other way out?

Comment: There are literally countless ways of doing that in VisualForce. David just suggested one.  My recommendation is to do some research, try one (or more) of what you find, and post here if you get stuck with your code.

Comment: Also, @heenalsikka if you had tried the solution I suggested, you would have seen the various images. One is a stop sign, one is a warning sign, etc.